# Can I perform transaction from different server - Blockchain

Tags: blockchain

Ethereum blockchain is decentralized and we have 4-5 servers which are mainnet,rinkeby,Kovan,ropsten and local Server.

If I create a Web App on Rinkeby so can other Server Acccount holder users can access that website and perform transactions(from other server) on it or not?

For Example if i create a voting app on rinkeby server, can i vote someone using mainnet server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the differences between **test** Ethereum networks, **public** Ethereum networks and **private** Ethereum networks first. Read more about Ethereum `public`, `test` and `private` networks [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/networks/). Also, each test network has its own compatibility with different Ethereum clients.

So, you are supposed to test your code using Ethereum private networks or test networks like `Rinkeby` and then deploy to `Mainnet`.